Quickfix python- creating a FIX message with PartyID repeating group
In my application, I am using python quickfix.
For FIX 4.4, I am trying to create a FIX message with PartyID group. But the sequence of fields In the message is different that what I had used. For ex:


import quickfix as fix

msg=fix.Message()

# then I set msgtype here

grp = fix.Group(453,0)

grp.setField(448,'valueOfPartyID')

grp.setField(447,'valueOfPartyIDSrc')

grp.setField(452,'valueOfPartyRole')

msg.addGroup(grp)

Using above piece of code, I was expecting to have a fix message where position of tags inside PartyID group to be as


8=FIX.4.4,......453=1,448=valueOfPartyID,447=valueOfPartyIDSrc,452=valueOfPartyRole,....10=`



But instead order of fields is as per below



`8=FIX.4.4,......453=1,447=valueOfPartyIDSrc,448=valueOfPartyID,452=valueOfPartyRole,....10=

Is there any way to ensure the order is retained by quickfix based on which field in the group is set first?
I have tried looking for Documentation of quickfix using python and same imementatuon on github which could point me to something useful, but there is hardly any Documentation around this.
I have tried to look if I can pass a data dictionary while creating a blank fix.Message(), but that is not a valid signature for fix.Message()

Click here and scroll down a few inches to "Python":
https://quickfixengine.org/c/documentation#item-repeating-groups-2
Notice that the code in those docs is not instantiating the generic classes Message and Group, but the specific classes quickfix42.MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh and quickfix42.MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh().NoMDEntries.
The generic classes do not have field ordering information; the specific ones do.
So what you need is something like:
import quickfix as fix

# I don't know what message you are using; replace "WhateverMessage" with that

msg = fix.WhateverMessage.NoParties()

grp = fix.WhateverMessage.Group(453,0)
grp.setField(448,'valueOfPartyID')
grp.setField(447,'valueOfPartyIDSrc')
grp.setField(452,'valueOfPartyRole')
msg.addGroup(grp)

